# Select number of rows from each category

Tags: mysql, sql

I have messages table:
Messages:

```
Id, Content, Category, createdAt 

1, test1, cat1, 2018-03-26 18:22:39  
2, test2, cat1, 2018-03-26 18:22:46 
3, test3, cat2, 2018-03-26 18:22:52 
4, test4, cat2, 2018-03-26 18:23:11  
5, test5, cat2, 2018-03-26 18:23:13
6, test6, cat1, 2018-03-26 18:23:17
```

From this data, I want to select 2 rows of each category i.e. Cat1 & Cat2 with 2 rows each.

So what will be the SQL query to retrieve this data? This is sample data and like this, I have thousands of rows and 20 to 25 different categories. So I want to retrieve the same number of rows from each category. Also, this rows should be in ascending order according to a createdAt column.

Expected Output(Assuming createdAt is latest of bottom rows):

```
Id, Content, Category, createdAt 

6, test6, cat1, 2018-03-26 18:23:17  
2, test2, cat1, 2018-03-26 18:22:46  
5, test5, cat2, 2018-03-26 18:23:13
4, test4, cat2, 2018-03-26 18:23:11
```

Comment: Specify the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: use  "group by Category"

Comment: I have added expected output in Question.. Group by category returning only single row for each category. So nested query might be needed in this scenario

Comment: Your table header has 4 columns, but table data has only 3 columns. createdAt seems to be missing. Is that column important?

Comment: Ok, I will add the value for createdAt as well

Comment: You want the two most recent rows for each category?

Comment: @Strawberry 2 in the scense for this example i want to but in real i want 200 from each category..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Dynamic Top
**In place of N you can use any number**

```
SELECT Id,Content,Category,createdAt
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               CASE 
                 WHEN @category != t.category THEN @rownum := 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 
               END AS rank,
               @category := t.category AS var_category
          FROM Table1 t
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @category := '') r
      ORDER BY t.Category,t.createdAt DESC) x
 WHERE x.rank <= 'N'
```

**In place of N you can use any number**

Output

```
ID  Content Category    createdAt
6   test6   cat1    2018-03-26T18:23:17Z
2   test2   cat1    2018-03-26T18:22:46Z
5   test5   cat2    2018-03-26T18:23:13Z
4   test4   cat2    2018-03-26T18:23:11Z
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00ca02/20

Comment: Again this is returning single row from each category. I need 2 rows from each category.

Comment: Check Now I Edited My Answer

Comment: Its working for 2 rows. But in real i want 200 rows from each category, So is it possible to generalize this query to specify the n number of records from each category?

Comment: Check now I added generalize answer also

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no row_Number() function is MySql it becomes a little bit more tricky.

```
select 
  a.Id, a.Content, a.Category, a.createdAt
from Table1 a
JOIN Table1 b ON a.Category = b.Category AND a.createdAt <= b.createdAt
GROUP BY a.Category, a.createdAt
having count(*) <= 2
order by Category, CreatedAt desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that rank is what you are looking for

```
SELECT
  (
    CASE category
    WHEN @curCat
      THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
    ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curCat := category END
  ) + 1 AS rank,
  category,
  id,
  content
FROM tab1,
  (SELECT
     @curRow := 0,
     @curType := '') r
ORDER BY category
         AND rank <= 2;
```